# Poor (network) performance of Interpreter["Time"]

Tags: date-and-time, internet

I was surprised to see that `Interpreter` requires external WR resources as this is not documented, at least not [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpreter.html).

On a 3Ghz iMac, took ~half a minute to process n=68 time strings:

```
timeData = {"0:12:15", "0:13:00", "0:17:00", "0:00:39", "0:00:25", "0:00:38", 
"0:00:48", "0:05:50", "0:03:34", "0:05:50", "0:00:22", "0:04:05", 
"0:00:07", "0:00:07", "0:00:46", "0:00:02", "0:00:32", "0:00:11", 
"0:00:31", "0:09:55", "0:00:07", "0:00:34", "0:00:36", "0:07:44", 
"0:00:11", "0:00:20", "0:02:29", "0:04:30", "0:00:56", "0:01:23", 
"0:00:05", "0:00:05", "0:00:18", "0:00:13", "0:00:21", "0:00:21", 
"0:00:06", "0:00:13", "0:00:56", "0:00:05", "0:00:15", "0:00:05", 
"0:01:38", "0:00:22", "0:01:43", "0:00:14", "0:09:06", "0:01:39", 
"0:03:17", "0:03:08", "0:00:45", "0:00:36", "0:00:38", "0:00:06", 
"0:00:08", "0:01:07", "0:00:08", "0:01:06", "0:00:11", "0:00:17", 
"0:00:08", "0:00:17", "0:00:09", "0:00:34", "0:00:25", "0:00:31", 
"0:00:07", "0:01:29"};

AbsoluteTiming [Interpreter["Time"][#] & /@ timeData ] // First

26.633811
```

Timing is much lower, ~3 seconds, though once I ran it and got:

"Interpreter::timeout : "A network operation for Interpreter timed out. Please try again later."

Users can define their own interpreters, but curious if it's possible to make at least part of the functionality available locally?  I can't imagine a simpler test case than time strings.

Comment: I posted on a similar issue in the [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/295422?p_p_auth=Za0vXknp).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. Use the listability of Interpreter to parallelize calls to WR servers:

   ```
    In[1]:= AbsoluteTiming[Interpreter["Time"][timeData]] // First  
    Out[1]= 6.551647
   ```
2. Use Structured interpreters to avoid calling WR servers altogether:

   ```
   In[2]:= AbsoluteTiming[Interpreter["StructuredTime"][timeData]] // First  
   Out[2]= 0.165715
   ```

In general you might want to refer to [this guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/InterpretingStrings.html), and to [pages that describe the single types](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/interpreter/Time.html).